# How to get a Unix timestamp for C (in double or float)

Tags: c, timestamp

How can I get a Unix time stamp for C, specifically showing decimal places. All the answers I have found elsewhere return an integer.

Comment: That's because the UNIX timestamp is an integer.

Comment: And what should the decimals signify?

Comment: See [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Definition: "Unix time is a single signed integer number which increments every second..."

Comment: @Syjin  Note: Your reference also says:  "The ISO C standard states that time_t must be an arithmetic type, but does not mandate any specific type or encoding for it."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) function returns an integer only.  Both 
[`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) and
[`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) return structures (different structures) with seconds and subseconds (microseconds for `gettimeofday()` and nanoseconds for `clock_gettime()`). You'd have to do an appropriate (but simple) computation to return that as a `double`.

There's no point in returning a current Unix timestamp as a `float`; you'd only get values accurate to a couple of minutes or so.

POSIX has officially deprecated `gettimeofday()`. However, Mac OS X for one does not have `clock_gettime()`, so you're likely to find `gettimeofday()` is more widely available.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long  t0 = time(0);
    float f0 = t0;
    float f1;
    float f2;

    long d_pos = 0;
    long d_neg = 0;

    while ((f1 = t0 + d_pos) == f0)
        d_pos++;
    while ((f2 = t0 + d_neg) == f0)
        d_neg--;

    printf("t0 = %ld; f0 = %12.0f; d_pos = %ld (f1 = %12.0f); d_neg = %ld (f2 = %12.0f)\n",
        t0, f0, d_pos, f1, d_neg, f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
t0 = 1385638386; f0 =   1385638400; d_pos = 79 (f1 =   1385638528); d_neg = -51 (f2 =   1385638272)
```

Comment: Instead of `long  t0 = time(0);`, recommend `time_t  t0 = time(0);` to match the return type of `time_t()`;

Comment: @chux: I chose `long` quite deliberately as being sufficiently large to hold the current values of Unix time, and without the possibility that it might be a floating point type (which the C standard does not preclude), and because the `printf()` format letters for `long` are fixed and readily known compared with completely unfixed and unknowable for `time_t`.  That isn't production code, in case you hadn't noticed; it illustrates a point.

Comment: Had the code been `long  t0 = (long) time(0)`, the deliberate type change would have been more apparent.  I was not certain of your choice of `long v. time_t` was intended, hence the recommendation.